# How to get better error output with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, error-detection

I was working on a project and got the following errors

```
Error (active)    the default constructor of "Input" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function EquationSolver  c:\Users\Kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\EquationSolver\EquationSolver\main.cpp 10
Error C2280 'Input::Input(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function  EquationSolver  <project_dir>\main.cpp  10
```

Since it is almost impossible to find the cause of the error from this, I tried compiling with gcc with `-Wall` and got following output

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:10:9: error: use of deleted function 'Input::Input()'
   Input input;
         ^~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
Input.hpp:16:7: note: 'Input::Input()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class Input
       ^~~~~
Input.hpp:16:7: error: use of deleted function 'Expressions::Expressions()'
In file included from Input.hpp:11:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
Expressions.hpp:8:7: note: 'Expressions::Expressions()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class Expressions
       ^~~~~~~~~~~
Expressions.hpp:8:7: error: uninitialized reference member in 'class Expressions'
Expressions.hpp:17:8: note: 'Expressions::Vec& Expressions::left' should be initialized
   Vec& left;
        ^~~~
Expressions.hpp:8:7: error: uninitialized reference member in 'class Expressions'
 class Expressions
       ^~~~~~~~~~~
Expressions.hpp:18:8: note: 'Expressions::Vec& Expressions::right' should be initialized
   Vec& right;
        ^~~~~
```

This output is much more verbose and quickly helped me find the origin, which was a misplaced `&` (class member should be `Vec left`, was `Vec& left`).

**Is it possible to make Visual Studio as verbose?**

When putting Visual Studio to `/Wall`, I get >1800 warnings, most completely unrelated to my project, but I still only get those two errors.

Comment: You should try to solve problems yourself. See [C# Compiler Options Listed by Category](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s2x2bzy.aspx). Also provide sample code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, example code is just doing `int& i;` instead of `int i;` inside a `struct` while using an implicit constructor. And I do not know how I could solve it other than doing `/Wall`